# Reading czech input using InputStreamReader

Tags: java, input, stream, codepages, reader

I am writing a server with protocol to translate text by client.
For getting the input code follows:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clntSock.getInputStream(), "CP852");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
```

The problem is that after printing out the input (for checking if its accepted correctly), it prints something like "îAU" instead of "ČAU".
I know I could use byte conversion, but wanted to do it this way and can't find the error. Please help

Comment: Are you sure it's not where you're printing the result that's garbling the output? For example if you're printing out in a Windows console, you may not get the proper output. Try to dump the data into a file with the correct encoding and open that file in an editor that supports the code page.

Comment: yes, or it is the `clntSock.getInputStream()` (which is differently encoded) ..or `System.out`.